# How to disable minutes and seconds in Mui Date and time picker?

Tags: material-ui, next.js, react-hook-form, date-fns

I am trying to use Mui date and time picker with disabling minutes and seconds. I disabled the minute with `minuteStep={60}`. There is not a second prompt. But Date and time picker picking random seconds. Is there any way I can omit the seconds or lock the seconds value to 0?

```
<Controller
                name="checkOut"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                    <FormControl sx={FCWidth}>
                      <DateTimePicker
                        {...field}
                        toolbarFormat=""
                        label="Check Out"
                        name="checkOut"
                        disablePast={true}
                        minutesStep={60}
                        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                      />
                      <FormHelperText error={true}>
                        {errors.checkOut?.message}
                      </FormHelperText>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Grid>
                )}
              />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if I understood right, you should add `views={['hours']}` in `TimePicker`

Answer (score 0):

In MUI 5, you should be able to do this with the `views` [property](https://mui.com/api/date-time-picker/#props). However, an open [bug](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/30237) prevents it from zeroing out the unused fields.

As a workaround, you can zero out the desired fields yourself by intercepting the `onChange` callback. Here's an example with `TimePicker`, React Hook Form 7, and Luxon:

```
<Controller
  name="startTime"
  render={({ field: { onChange, ref, ...props }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <TimePicker
      label="Start time"
      renderInput={(props) => (
        <TextField {...props} helperText={error?.message} />
      )}
      onChange={(date) => onChange(toDateTime(date).startOf('minute'))}
      {...props}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Note that `toDateTime` is a helper function that accepts a Luxon `DateTime`, JS `Date`, or ISO date string and returns a `DateTime`.